# rclone failure when syncing on local filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sync

Ubuntu 16.04
Rclone v1.36

Failing to sync two directories locally.
Running as root, I can write to the directories.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/sxsroot/data/spi/spi--sftp-ftp.laserwords.com/Document# rclone sync /tmp/source /tmp/destination
2017/08/29 02:27:51 NOTICE: Config file "/root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found - using defaults
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Local file system at /tmp/destination: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Attempt 1/3 failed with 0 errors and: error reading source directory "": directory not found
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Local file system at /tmp/destination: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Attempt 2/3 failed with 0 errors and: error reading source directory "": directory not found
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Local file system at /tmp/destination: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2017/08/29 02:27:51 ERROR : Attempt 3/3 failed with 0 errors and: error reading source directory "": directory not found
2017/08/29 02:27:51 Failed to sync: error reading source directory "": directory not found
root@ubuntu:/var/sxsroot/data/spi/spi--sftp-ftp.laserwords.com/Document# ls /tmp/source
context.sh
root@ubuntu:/var/sxsroot/data/spi/spi--sftp-ftp.laserwords.com/Document# ls /tmp/destination
one_env
root@ubuntu:/var/sxsroot/data/spi/spi--sftp-ftp.laserwords.com/Document#
```

PS: Could someone with 1500+ rep please create a tag for rclone?

Answer (score 0):

This worked ok when I used my home directory ~ rather than tmp.

Asking the Rclone channel I got this reply:

> maybe you have some restricting mount options on /tmp ?

Which I don't think I have. Anyway it didn't work for me in temp.